# Check if the information entered by a user is equal to the information in a txt file in php

Tags: php, html

I have a code that sends the information entered by a user to a select, but I want the select to only show countries from a txt that I have prepared called "dictionary.txt" and if the information entered is not the one that belongs to that file so that it does not appear in the select.

Here's my code:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
    if (!file_exists("countries.txt"))
    {
        $files = fopen("countries.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
        fclose($files);
    }

    if(isset($_GET['country']) && !empty(trim($_GET['country'])))   // +
    {
        $country = $_GET['country'];
        $info = $country."\r\n";            // +
        $files = fopen("countries.txt", "a") or die("Error");
        fwrite($files,$info);
        fclose($files);
       
    }
?>
    <form action="#" method="GET">      <!-- -->
        <input type="text" name="country" placeholder="Introduce a country">
        <input type="submit" name="btnsend" value="Send">
    </form>
    <select name="countrys"><option selected value="">--------</option>
    <?php
        $lines = array_unique(file("countries.txt"));
        $correctLines = array_unique(file("dictionaries.txt"));
        foreach($lines as $key => $value):
            echo '<option value="'.$key.'">'.$value.'</option>';
            endforeach;
    ?>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Using both the `{ ... }` style and the exceptionally rare `foreach(): ... endforeach;` style together is not helping the readability of this code.

Comment: Are you asking "How do I intersect two arrays?"

Comment: what I want is that only in the input you can put names of countries that are stored in a txt and that if the information does not correspond to that of the txt nothing is written in the select

Comment: You should probably screen the entry before writing it, as in check that the entry is valid before your `fwrite` call. You should also explore writing functions to better encapsulate what's going on here. If you know the data in the written file is clean, then writing the option list is super easy.

Comment: i'm going to try that ,thanks

Comment: consider using a database my friend. it will save you much headache in the long run.